# How do I remove the links from product names in WooCommerce order emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

When a customer receives their woocommerce order completed email, there are 2 columns.
In the left column is the product name and in the right column is the download link.

How can I remove the link(s) from the left column product name(s)?

[image: See this screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you already found a solution, I had the same problem and I found the solution from this link: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-product-link-in-order-emails/

I replaced line 44 from email-downloads.php with the following line:

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $download['product_name'] ); ?>
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvW3S.png)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is a great solution. Thank you!